# Efficiently remove lines from fileA that contains string from fileB

Tags: python, perl, bash, unix

FileA contains lines
FileB contains words

How can I **efficiently** remove lines from FileB containing words found in FileA?

I tried the following, and I'm not even sure if they work because it's taking so long to run.

**Tried `grep`:**

```
grep -v -f <(awk '{print $1}' FileB.txt) FileA.txt > out
```

**Also tried `python`:**

```
f = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
out = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
bad_words = f.read().splitlines()

with open('FileA') as master_lines:
  for line in master_lines:
    if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
      out.write(line)
```

**FileA:**

```
abadan refinery is one of the largest in the world.
a bad apple spoils the barrel.
abaiara is a city in the south region of brazil.
a ban has been imposed on the use of faxes
```

**FileB:**

```
abadan
abaiara
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
a bad apple spoils the barrel.
a ban has been imposed on the use of faxes
```

Comment: How big are your files?

Comment: `FileA` with lines has 3M lines, `FileB` with the keywords is about 200k

Comment: @user1899415 Can you post from sample data from both files? Also, make sure your files do not have windows formatting. You can covert them to by using `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: @jaypal edited to include sample data and desired output

Comment: Loading FileB into a python `set` or `dict` will allow you to do much faster lookup, so I expect the results will be much better if you do that. BTW you got FileA and FileB mixed in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you have look good so may be its time to try a good scripting language. Try to run the following `perl` script and see if it reports back any faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
#use warnings;

open my $LOOKUP, "<", "fileA" or die "Cannot open lookup file: $!";
open my $MASTER, "<", "fileB" or die "Cannot open Master file: $!";
open my $OUTPUT, ">", "out" or die "Cannot create Output file: $!";

my %words;
my @l;

while (my $word = <$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp($word);
    ++$words{$word};
}

LOOP_FILE_B: while (my $line = <$MASTER>) {
    @l = split /\s+/, $line;
        for my $i (0 .. $#l) {
            if (defined $words{$l[$i]}) {
                next LOOP_FILE_B;
            }
        }
    print $OUTPUT "$line"
}
```

Comment: Whoa that is amazing, it ran and finished in about 10 seconds!

Comment: @user1899415 I have made a change to the script. The first version only looked at words that matched the start of the line. I misunderstood your requirement based on your sample data. The updated version looks for entire line for words matching from words file. Do run the test again as your initial output is likely to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I refuse to believe that Python can't at least match the performance of Perl on this one.  This is my quick attempt at a more efficient version of solving this in Python.  I'm using [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to optimize the search part of this problem.  The & operator returns a new set with elements common to both sets.

This solution takes 12 seconds to run on my machine for a fileA with 3M lines and fileB with 200k of words and the perl takes 9.  The biggest slow down seems to be re.split, which seems to be faster than string.split in this case.

Please comment on this answer if you have any suggestions to improve the speed.

```
import re

filea = open('Downloads/fileA.txt')
fileb = open('Downloads/fileB.txt')

output = open('output.txt', 'w')
bad_words = set(line.strip() for line in fileb)

splitter = re.compile("\s")
for line in filea:
    line_words = set(splitter.split(line))
    if bad_words.isdisjoint(line_words):
        output.write(line)

output.close()
```

Comment: Sure.  If I still have battery left.  If my laptop dies I'll do it tomorrow.  The perl solution is sucking up lots of juice (still running) ;)  ... If you want to recreate the data, download http://norvig.com/big.txt (100,000 lines or so) and duplicate it using cat and >>.  Grab a word list and truncate it to 200k with head -c200k.  This should get you about the same size data I'm testing with.

Comment: @jaypal I don't make any guarantees about the correctness of my Python solution.  It works for the sample data that the original user posted.  I didn't look at it too carefully for the larger data set.  It obviously doesn't take punctuation into count either.

Comment: using a regular spit instead of a regex object is 4 time faster on my machine `line_words = set(line.split("\s"))`. I am using `Python 2.7.3`.

Comment: @jaypal nice work... the updated perl script takes 9 seconds.  I tried updating my python solution to use generators, but that only saved a second.  The biggest time sink in my Python solution is splitting the strings.  Any body out there have thoughts how to optimize that portion?

Comment: @jaypal no worries!  Your solution is still in the lead /w 9 seconds.  I read the manual for the set module in Python, and using isdisjoint cut out my need for a call to len each time.  This brought my solution down to 12 seconds.  I'll mess with this more later... I refuse to let Perl win, even if it is only a difference of 3 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

Using grep

```
grep -v -Fwf fileB fileA
```

Comment: The `python` solution takes `0m1.053s`,but your `grep` solution takes `0m0.608s` with the files im using. I would definitively use this solution for efficiency.