# accessing text between specific words in UNIX multiple times

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

if the file is like this:

```
ram_file
abc
123
end_file
tony_file
xyz
456
end_file
bravo_file
uvw
789
end_file
```

now i want to access text between `ram_file` and `end_file`, `tony_file` & `end _file` and `bravo_file` & `end_file` simultaneously. I tried `sed` command but i don't know how to specify `*_file` in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should do the job for you.

This solution threat the `end_file` as an end of block, and all other `xxxx_file` as start of block.
It will not print text between the block of there are some, like in my example `do not print this`.

```
awk '/end_file/{f=0} f; /_file/ && !/end_file/ {f=1}' file
abc
123
xyz
456
uvw
789
```

```
cat file
ram_file
abc
123
end_file
do not print this
tony_file
xyz
456
end_file
nor this data
bravo_file
uvw
789
end_file
```

---

If you like some formatting, it can be done easy with `awk`

```
awk -F_ '/end_file/{printf (f?RS:"");f=0} f; /file/ && !/end_file/ {f=1;print "-Block-"++c"--> "$1}' file
-Block-1--> ram
abc
123

-Block-2--> tony
xyz
456

-Block-3--> bravo
uvw
789
```

Comment: +1; probably better to anchor the `..._file` regexes.

Comment: +1: for better solution and making us delete our answers! `:P`

Comment: @jaypal Uff, hope I did not made any feel bad, not my intention :)  Its not always good to understand what the request is and it may take some turn to get it ok.

Comment: @Jotne Nope not at all. Yesterday, I had someone helping me debug a [`perl` script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22494074/970195) for over 3 hours. We got the performance down from several minutes to 9 seconds. Getting someone to debug your answer is a tough task, so I'm really appreciative of that. It's only when you try to resolve all edge scenarios you open up the learning door! Cheers and thank you! Keep on doing the good stuff!!